# Installing PyAudio in PyCharm on Windows

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

First of all my project is setup with `venv` and please note that I am unable to use `conda`.

I am having issues installing `PyAudio` via PyCharms on Windows. I have compiled the `PortAudio` files by myself following various other guides. Now I am trying to install it via the Python Interpreter in PyCharm and can't get it to work. Have tried adding the Include directory in the options via `--global-option="-I/path-here"`, doesn't get recognized, same with adding it to the Interpreter Paths.

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "portaudio.h": No such file or directory
```

I've had no issues on Linux, since installing PortAudio is simple and the PyAudio installation then works via PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, whilst writing this in complete desparation and before I throw the effort away: I switched to Python 3.6 (was using 3.7), installed PyAudio on first try without any problems. So if anyone comes across this problem, please try this. It even says that `PyAudio Version 0.2.11` only supports Python up to 3.6.

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download the PyAudio module and install it from here: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files

Answer (score 0):

Part 1. In PyCharm:

- go to "File";
- "Settings";
- "Project";
- push this button ">"  [image];
- "Python interpreter";
- push a gear wheel button  [image];
- "Add";
- "System Interpreter";
- choose python version installed on your system;
- If you see "PyAudio" in the list it's mean that you finished. If you don't see PyAudio then go to part 2.

Part 2. For windows 10:

- push "Start" button;
- right mouse button click on "This PC";
- "Properties";
- "Advanced system settings";
- "Environment Variables";
- in "User Variables" double click on "Path";
- make sure that paths "python3.x.x/script" and "python3.x.x" for your python version (which you choose in the part 1 of this instruction) are on the top of your list. If not, click "Move up" button [image] ;
- push "Ok" buttons.

Part 3. Installing PyAudio

Go to "Start" -> "cmd" -> type "pip install pyaudio" and push "Enter" button.
That's all.